# Randomize Image Fade In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can anyone help me about my problem.
i have a 5 images (which is set in a specific position) with the use of bootstrap then i want it to have an animation to be specific a FADE animation on page load here's my mark up and js and its working properly but I want my image to show randomly can anyone help me.

```js
$(function () {
            $('#fds img').each(function (i) {
               $(this).delay((i++) * 1000).fadeTo(2000, 1);
            })
        });
```

```html
 <div id="fds">
        <div class="col-md-12 margin-b-2" style="padding-left: 0; padding-top: 20px">
            <div class="com-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img id="img1" class="thumbnail" src="../img/1.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" height="300" width="330" onclick="javascript:modalImg1();" />
            </div>
            <div class="com-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img id="img2" class="thumbnail" src="../img/2.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" height="300" width="330" onclick="javascript:modalImg2();" />
            </div>
            <div class="com-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img id="img3" class="thumbnail" src="../img/3.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" height="300" width="330" onclick="javascript:modalImg3();" />
            </div>
            <div class="com-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img id="img4" class="thumbnail" src="../img/4.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" height="300" width="330" onclick="javascript:modalImg4();" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img id="img5" class="thumbnail" src="../img/5.png" alt="Alternate Text" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px" height="300" width="1350" onclick="javascript:modalImg5();" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
      function Shuffle(o) {
        for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
      }; //stole...borrowed from CSS tricks!
      rand = [];
      $('#fds img').each(function(i) {
        rand.push(i);
      })
      Shuffle(rand);
      for (i = 0; i < rand.length; i++) {
        $('#fds img').eq(rand[i]).delay(i * 1000).fadeTo(2000, 1);
      }
    });
```

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/rdc47yqL/**

So, process is: get indexes of images, place them in array, randomize/shuffle array),iterate through randomized array, 
and target images by using eq() selector.

Comment: Thank you sir :) it helps a lot but the transition is so fast... where should i put a delay o should i add a delay to the fade?

Comment: Np, just play with values, e.g delay(i * 1800) looks fine to me?